# qsort fails to sort large array of strings

Tags: c, sorting, gcc

I'm using `qsort` to sort an array of `i` strings of size `256`, such as `char *arr = malloc(i * 256)` -- was actully done with reallocs inside a loop. Each string contains, among text, a number, which I use as the comparison element:

```
int                                                               
cmp(const void *a, const void *b)                                               
{                                                                               
  double atime = get_time((char*)a);                                            
  double btime = get_time((char*)b);                                            
  return (atime > btime) - (atime < btime);                                     
}
```

When `i` is small, it works. With a large `i`, it fails to sort the array correctly. `get_time` is working. I was using it with a custom heapsort implementation before, which worked flawlessly.

I added the following to cmp to check what was happening:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Comparing %f to %f, result: %d.\n", atime, btime, (atime > btime) - (atime < btime));
```

It seems that all comparisons are correct, but not all comparisons are being made. `arr` has several strings containing `1.something`, however I couldn't find any comparison between numbers greater than `1` in the output. The call to `qsort` is as follows:

```
qsort((void*)arr, i-1, MAX_ROW_LEN, cmp);
```

It's the same parameters I used to pass to my heapsort function, but it doesn't work.

[Complete code](http://pastebin.com/BGq7Mg6w), and [example file (fails to sort)](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=66915353215374579314).

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_ROW_LEN 256
#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 256

/* Return the start time of the event or -1 if no time. */
static double
get_time(const char *event)
{
  if (!event || event[0] == '%')
    return -1;
  size_t tok = strcspn(event, " ") + 2;
  double ans = strtod(event + tok, NULL);
  if (!ans)
    return -1;
  return ans;
}

/*static inline*/ int
cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  double atime = get_time((char*)a);
  double btime = get_time((char*)b);
  return (atime > btime) - (atime < btime);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* process parameters */
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Supply a file to sort.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (strlen(argv[1]) > MAX_FILENAME_LEN) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Filename too long.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  /* read the file */
  printf("Now processing %s.\n", argv[1]);
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!f) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open out. Errno %d.\n", errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  char *trace = malloc(MAX_ROW_LEN);
  char *header = malloc(MAX_ROW_LEN);
  size_t i = 1, j = 1;
  while (fgets(trace + (i-1)*MAX_ROW_LEN, MAX_ROW_LEN, f)) {
    /* (if we can't get the time, it's part of the header) */
    if (get_time(trace + (i-1)*MAX_ROW_LEN) != -1) {
      trace = realloc((void*)trace, (++i)*MAX_ROW_LEN);
    } else {
      strncpy(header + (j-1)*MAX_ROW_LEN, trace + (i-1)*MAX_ROW_LEN,
          MAX_ROW_LEN);
      header = realloc((void*)header, (++j)*MAX_ROW_LEN);
    }
  }
  if (!feof(f)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file. Errno %d.\n", ferror(f));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Read %zu lines.\n", i);
  fclose(f);
  /* write the header */
  f = fopen("out_fixed", "w");
  if (!f) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open out_fixed. Errno %d.\n", errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  for (size_t k = 0; k < j-1; ++k) {
    /* (there is '%' in comments, can't print formatted) */
    fputs((void*)(header + k*MAX_ROW_LEN), f);
  }
  /* sort */
  printf("Started sorting.\n");
  time_t start = time(NULL);
  qsort((void*)trace, i-1, MAX_ROW_LEN, cmp);
  printf("Ended sorting, took %fs.\n", difftime(time(NULL), start));
  /* write the sorted trace */
  printf("Started writting to disk.\n");
  start = time(NULL);
  for (size_t k = 0; k < i-1; ++k) {
    fprintf(f, "%s", trace + k*MAX_ROW_LEN);
  }
  printf("Took %fs.\n", difftime(time(NULL), start));
  /* flush */
  printf("Closing file (fflush)\n");
  start = time(NULL);
  if (fclose(f)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close out_fixed. Errno %d.\n", errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Took %fs.\n", difftime(time(NULL), start));
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any numbers that start with `1.` in your example file.

Comment: Allocating memory like that can lead to bad performance; you should probably double the amount of memory allocated each time.  However, that is not directly the cause of your problem.  Have you printed the values being sorted?  It might be more efficient/effective to have and sort an array of pointers to variable length strings — it'll use less memory since most data lines are nowhere near 256 characters long.

Comment: Congratulations on a proper use of `feof()` — that happens seldom around here.

Comment: Anyone checking the data should note that the first 140 or so lines (out of 700k lines) are not the operational data.

Comment: Also, there are no entries where column 2 contains a value bigger than 0.655188796.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested your code and your example input file and it seems to work fine. In your question you say:

> ... has several strings containing 1.something, however I couldn't find
>   any comparison between numbers greater than 1 in the output.

But there are no such lines in your example input file.

Given this example line of your input:

```
12 0.475183170 rank3 STATE fill_row
```

This line in `get_time` is going to skip over any leading digits in your double:

```
size_t tok = strcspn(event, " ") + 2;
```

`strcspn` returns the number of characters that it had to read before finding the "needle" so in this case it will return 2. You then add 2 to that and then use that as a pointer offset into your `event` string, meaning that you are passing a pointer to `.475183170` instead of `0.475183170`.

You'd be better off just using `strchr` here anyway:

```
char *tok = strchr(event, ' ');
if (!tok) {
    return -1;
}
double ans = strtod(tok, NULL);
```

The subsequent `strtod` will skip leading whitespace for you, so you don't need to get super fancy.

Comment: Thanks! I uploaded the wrong file, but it seems the issue was `strcspn`. Replacing it with `strchr` fixed the issue.

Comment: The issue isn't with `strcspn`, it's that you are adding `2` to the return value of `strcspn`. Your original code would work if you changed that line to: `size_t tok = strcspn(event, " ");` (dropping the `+ 2`)

Comment: I meant "with my use of `strcspn`".